# JQuery - Fetch input field value from another iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, ember.js

I have an app running within a webpage. Basically the form is in a different frame and my code is in different frame.

When trying to access the parent frame I'm getting the below error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
> "http://localhost:10001" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I will not be able to change the domains of both the page to same as I don't have access to the complete document.

Is there a workaround to access the element from another frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access an  with different origin using JavaScript.

If it's just a local env situation, you can disable your browser built-in Cross-Origin protection (don't forget to turn it back on !).

You should then be able to use [Window.frameElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement) the access the parent of your iframe.

Please have a look at this answer which greatly explains : [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)